# jquery function is lost at first call

Tags: jquery, recordset

I would like to fire up jquery function each time i click a record from db. The function works when I click the first record in the list then it disapears when I reload the page and click the last record the function works for that record for the records before. I am not looking for each() function.

Any ideas please

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".icon_divs").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
          //My code....

   });
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you distinguish the db records? are you passing such variable to ajax? Can you please post more code?

Answer (score 0):

You are question is a bit ambiguous. I believe I understand your situation here.

according to your code, it says on load of the document you are creating a a click handler for 'icon_divs' class.

say you have something like this

```
<div class="icon_divs">
    <img src="icon1"/>
    <img src="icon2"/>
    <img src="icon3"/>
</div>
```

now when you click on the first icon the first time, your click handler holds the value of the first icon. Even when you click on any other icon under the div.icon_divs the handler still assumes you have clicked on the first one.

So you have to let the handler know which element under the class has been clicked. It called delegation.

```
$('.icon_divs').on('click', 'img', function () {
// your code
});
```

Comment: I beleive my question isn't so clear as i hoped. let me explain. let's i have 3 divs
    <div class="icon_divs">
        <img src="icon1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="icon_divs">
        <img src="icon2"/>
    </div>
    <div class="icon_divs">
        <img src="icon3"/>
    </div>
i click the first div ajax fuction works and get lost. i mean when i click the 2nd div the function doesn't work anymore. If I reload the page and click the 3rd one the function works the 2nd works if i click the 3rd NOT WORKING i click the 1st works and that will be the last time until i reload the page again.

Comment: Did you make sure if the Ajax post request was successful ? And still its best to delegate events on the specific element !!

Answer (score 0):

Solved
The problem was I had to refer to the exact div

ex;
$(".class1 .class2").on("click .....